# Associating Application User with existing User Class in MVC Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity, account

I'm trying to make a web application using ASP.NET MVC5 and Entity Framework 6. I'm come to a point where I've an existing database with the class User (with id, username, password, email...) and now I'd like to configure the login and registration using this class (instead of ApplicationUser, but still using the scaffolded code). I've researched many ways to do it, but with no sucess. Is there anyway I can do this or am I taking the wrong approach? Thank you for your help.

Note: I'm also using a new database connection (not the defaultConnetion).

Comment: Why create you own user class? It's pretty easy to extend the IndentityUser class. http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx#The-Heart-of-it-All---ApplicationDbContext

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing database and want asp.net Identity to use those tables you need to make custom implementation of IUserStore.

You can find more information [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity#userstore). That post seams a bit overwhelming but you should read it.